# React Select menu color showing blue with no highlight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am new to react and new to react select. I have a fairly simple issue I think the problem is my react-select menu is totally blue with options with no highlight indicator.

[image]

I do not know why this is happening I want the default settings for react-select to occur for this:

My code is this:

```
<Col lg="6" style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>
                    <Label for="tdc">TDC</Label>
                    <Select
                      className="select"
                      //isMulti
                      id="TDC"
                      placeholder="Search TDC..."
                      value={hide ? null : TDCOption}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeTDC}
                      options={this.state.TDCNo}
                      autoComplete="off"
                      isDisabled={this.state.disable}
                      styles={{
                        control: (provided, state) => ({
                          ...provided,
                          boxShadow: 'none',
                          borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
                          borderBottom: this.state.isEmpty2 ? '2px solid red' : '1px solid 
                           black',
                        }),
                      }}
                    />
                  </Col>

Could you please help me solve this issue?
```

Comment: You can not add // to comment out lines within the (jsx) markup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is it that which is causing the problem?

Comment: and you definitely can